# How To Trigger "info/connected" As "snapshot.value == true" Of Firebase Realtime?

Tags: flutter, firebase-realtime-database

This code is similar to firebase's [presence solution for Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/presence). Unfortunetely, the `.info/connected` is triggered as `false` everytime

What to do to trigger this event with `true` value?

```
Future handlePresence(int userId) async {
  FirebaseDatabase realtime = FirebaseDatabase.instance;
  var statusRealtimeRef = realtime.ref('/status/$userId');
  var statusFirestoreRef = firestore.doc('/user/$userId');
  

  realtime.ref().child('.info/connected').onValue.listen((event) {
    if (event.snapshot.value == false) {
      statusFirestoreRef.set(_statusFirestore(false), SetOptions(merge: true));
      return;
    }

    // ------> THIS PART IS NEVER CALLED <------
    statusRealtimeRef.onDisconnect().set(_statusRealtime(false)).then((value) {
      statusRealtimeRef.set(_statusRealtime(true));
      statusFirestoreRef.set(_statusFirestore(true), SetOptions(merge: true));
    });
  });

  return null;
}

_statusFirestore(bool online) {
  return {'state': online ? 'on' : 'off', 'lastChanged': FieldValue.serverTimestamp()};
}

_statusRealtime(bool online) {
  return {'state': online ? 'on' : 'off', 'lastChanged': ServerValue.timestamp};
}
```

Comment: It is expected that a listener to `.info/connected` initially fires with `false` as it takes a moment to establish the connection. Are you saying that it never triggers with `true` after that? That'd indicate that the client can't connect to the server. Can you check if you can write something to the Realtime Database?

Comment: Solved. It was as you told me, never triggered with true. I realized the database URL is null. Then I use `FirebaseDatabase.instanceFor` instead of `FirebaseDatabase.instance` with setting database URL manually, and it worked. BTW,  why the first option is not working ?

Comment: Good to hear you figured it out. The database URL missing is a common problem these days. The SDK used to be able to figure it out on its own, but now with the ability to host databases in different regions you have to make sure you download the `google-services.json` *after* creating the default database, or (recommended) always specify the database URL in your code.

Comment: For the fluter users: after adding the firebase realtime the `firebase_options.dart` did not update. It contains configurations like database URL etc. Just execute `flutter configure` on the root of the project. And everything will be fine, then you won't need to use `FirebaseDatabase.instanceFor` instead of `FirebaseDatabase.instance`